# Calculating distance between two addresses in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am attempting to calculate the distance between two addresses with the gmapdistance package in a shiny app. I have the code working in an r script and not in a shiny app:

```r
distance <- function(addr1, addr2) {
  meters <- gmapsdistance(origin = "addr1",
                          destination = "addr2",
                          mode = "driving",
                          key = Sys.getenv("KEY"))$Distance
  miles <- meters/1609.34
  return(miles)
```

However, when I put this into a shiny app, my code fails with this error:
Warning: Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'xmlChildren' applied to an object of class "NULL

here is the code:

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput(inputId = "addr1",
                label = h4("Enter address 1:"),
                value = ""),
      textInput(inputId = "addr2",
                label = h4("Enter address 2:"),
                value = "")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("value")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent ({
    input$addr1
    input$addr2
  }, {
    meters <- gmapsdistance(origin = input$addr1,
                            destination = input$addr2,
                            mode = "driving",
                            key = ("API_KEY"))$Distance
       miles <- meters/1609.34
       return(miles)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

any insight / solutions would be really appreciated, thank you!!

Comment: Is that your Google Maps API key in the code? You probably don't want to make that public.

Comment: If you do `print(miles)` instead of `return(miles)`, that could work (you should see the distance in the R console).

Comment: @neilfws that is not my real key

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent thank you for the input but sadly that did not fix the error: 'Warning: Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'xmlChildren' applied to an object of class "NULL"'